# Is there a price reduction for a magic item with a cooldown?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting

A *cooldown* is present in some existing supernatural or spell-like abilities (e.g. many dragons' breath weapons). That is, after the ability's used, the user must wait some time (either set or rolled) before the ability can be used again.

Are there rules for creating magic items at a reduced cost that have cooldowns between uses?

Comment: An example of an item that you want to create might be a good idea and might help to be used to set a price as an example in the answers.

Comment: Now I'm wondering the price of a usable-all-the-time-for-building [*lyre of building*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/lyre-of-building).

Answer (score 1):

**No, there are no rules about magic item 'cooldowns'.** Cooldowns are a rare function in Pathfinder and are usually used to limit exceptionally powerful but iconic abilities. If the magic/ability/function has a built-in cooldown, there is no discount for creating it because the enchantment would include that limitation.

Otherwise, items generally have charges instead; however, you could probably adapt a homerule from the existing magic item creation rules. I wouldn't reduce the price by more than 15-20% compared to an item that is at-will. Talk to your GM!

[Magic Item Creation Rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Magic-Item-Creation) for reference.

> Charges per day|Divide by (5/**charges**)
>
> Use-activated or continuous|Spell level x caster level x 2,000 gp2

Bolded for clarification, mine.

Answer (score 1):

### No, but you can make it work with existing magic item creation rules.

One of the rules of magic item creation is to always compare the effect you're making with similar effects before pricing your item.  The only existing limit on magic items that makes it so they can only be used sometimes is the charges/day limit.  To make your item with a cooldown, you'll have to compare it to that.

Now, Pathfinder's rules make a bunch of systemic assumptions about the game that you're playing, because it would be hard to generate rules-based numbers otherwise.  Specifically, it assumes a 4-encounter day, and roughly 10 rounds per combat.  Thus, an item with 4 charges per day (the maximum number of charges that gives a discount) can be used once per encounter.

The [Magic Item Creation Rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Magic-Item-Creation) give the following formula for calculating a discount on an item with limited charges per day:

> Charges per day|Divide by (5/charges)
>
> Use-activated or continuous|Spell level x caster level x 2,000 gp2

In order for your cooldown item to provide a discount, it should then be usable no more than once per encounter.  An item with 5 charges per day costs the same amount as an item usable at-will.  In the same way, an item with a short enough cooldown that it can be used more than once per encounter should cost the same as an item usable at-will, based on the existing magic item creation rules.  If the item is a combat item, then the cooldown should be at least 10 rounds to provide a discount.  If it's a non-combat item, it should be much longer, probably minutes or even hours, depending on the effect.

To calculate the appropriate discount, try to figure out how many times the user could use the item in a typical adventuring day, assuming they're trying to use it a lot.  Take that number and plug it into the "charges per day" formula, and you have your discount.